# getting the value from a qwtslider

Tags: qt, slider, vtk, qwt

I have a qwtslider and I want to get the value to apply on a vtkImagePlaneWidget, but i can't figure out how to do this. I've been using getValue() but it won't work.

I have the function to transfer it:

```
void planevolume::SplaneX()
{
    double xvalue=ui->Slider->getValue();// this does not work
    planeX->SetSliceIndex(xvalue);
    ui->qvtkWidget->update();
```

that will work as a slot, and

```
// X Slider
      ui->doubleSpinBox->setDecimals(0);
      ui->doubleSpinBox->setMaximum(xmax);
      ui->doubleSpinBox->setSingleStep(1.0);
      ui->doubleSpinBox->setValue((xmax-xmin)/2.0);
      ui->Slider->setRange(xmin, xmax, 1.0);
      ui->Slider->setScale(xmin, xmax+1.0, (xmax+1.0)/4.0);
      ui->Slider->setValue((xmax-xmin)/2.0);
      connect(ui->Slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), ui->doubleSpinBox, SLOT(setValue(double)));
      connect(ui->doubleSpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), ui->Slider, SLOT(setValue(double)));

connect(ui->Slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), this, SLOT(SplaneX()));
```

how can i do it? does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you compile this code?

double xvalue=ui->Slider->getValue();// this does not work

you must write:

double xvalue=ui->Slider->**value**();

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware that `vtkImagePlaneWidget::SetSliceIndex` takes **int** as a parameter, not **double**? What range is your **xmin** and **xmax**? Default conversion of double to int will truncate all your fractional stepping (like 1/4th of slider step i see). Also you are connecting to non-existent signals and slots on `QDoubleSpinBox`. `setValue` and `valueChanged` take **int** as parameter, not **double**.